# Bitbucket import to Azure DevOps including LFS

Tags: git, azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-repos

We have a BitBucket server and we'd like to migrate the repository to Azure DevOps. This works using the Import repository option in Azure DevOps, but when we clone the Azure DevOps repository, we get an error about LFS items (essentially "*LFS items not found*").

[image]

I have tried this:

1. `git clone <BitBucket clone URL>`, then
2. `cd <repository>`, then
3. `git lfs fetch –all`, then
4. `git remote set-url origin <new Azure DevOps clone URL>`, then
5. `git push --mirror origin`, and finally
6. `git lfs push origin --all`

And this hasn't really worked. The repo size of the BitBucket cloned dir is not the same as the cloned Azure DevOps repo (that's how you compare if the LFS part has worked, right?)

Here's what we observed by performing the above steps:

1. When we clone just the BitBucket repository locally, only the master branch is shown. If I `git checkout -b <branch_name>`, it shows up locally (in red). I understand it is the standard behaviour.
2. `git lfs fetch –all` fetches LFS items whose total size is < 40 mb (not gb). Is that normal?
3. `git push --mirror origin` finishes completely.
4. `git lfs push origin --all` finishes completely.

This didn't help (although the LFS error wasn't showing up anymore), because we only see the master branch in Azure DevOps [NOTE: We are not doing BitBucket to Azure DevOps import directly now, we are cloning the BitBucket repo, then pulling LFS then pushing them to Azure DevOps]. There are like at least 50 - 60 branches in the BitBucket repo. Do we need to manually `git checkout -b <branch name>` then `git push` them, or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

One other thing we've tried is that we directly imported BitBucket repo to Azure DevOps, then cloned the former separately then followed the 6 steps above for LFS. Now, because it's a direct import, all the branch show up initially. But we found out that after step #6 (`git lfs push origin --all`), the Azure DevOps repo only contains master branch. everything else gets removed/deleted.

I hope it's all making sense.

I don't know what really is going on. Can you please help?